# SASS/SCSS: Include (not import) contents of another CSS or SCSS file into an existing file?

Tags: css, sass

I have two files:

- parent.scss
- child.scss (or .css, does not matter)

*parent.scss* has the following content (pseudo code)

```
.some-class {
    @include(child.scss);
}
```

And *child.scss*:

```
.foobar {
    color: red;
}
```

The resulting *parent.css* should then have the following content:

```
.some-class .foobar {
    color: red;
}
```

=> It should include the contents of child.css wrapped in the ".some-class" class.

The reason for this is that I have some pre-compiled CSS files whose rules I'd like to include in my SCSS file, BUT the rules should be wrapped into a "parent" rule (*.some-class* in my example above).

Comment: You can wrap your child contents into the [`@mixin` and `@include`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) it.